# datalist in usercontrol throws nullreference exception while trying to assign datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, datalist

I moved a Datalist Control on an aspx page on to a usercontrol and referenced it to the aspx page. In the process, I also moved the source code for the datalist( ItemDataBound and Display methods). I am using a "Datatable" as the source for the Datalist population. after I move the control in to a user control, it throws me a NullReference right  when i try to assign the datatable as a source to the datalist.

```
public partial class Controls_ProductSpecifications : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //no code yet here...
    }

    public void DisplaySpecifications(SearchResultItem sri,bool IsMobilePage)
    {
        List<Category> breadcrumbCategories = sri.BreadcrumbCategories;
        Category templateCat =  breadcrumbCategories[breadcrumbCategories.Count - 1];

        ParametricColumnSortOrder customDimSortOrder = null;
        int rowPosition = 0; // manufacturer, product category, rohs
        bool isUnclassified = false;

        // -- get the sorted parametric list from database
        if (templateCat.Id.ToString() != null)
            customDimSortOrder = new ParametricColumnSortOrder(Convert.ToInt64(templateCat.Id), false, true);

        //List<ParametricAttributeGroup> plist = sri.ParametricDimensions;
        if (breadcrumbCategories[0].Name == "Unclassified")
        {
            ////if (breadcrumbCategories.Count > 1)
            ////{
            ////    //---{ Create an unclassifed attribute group } 
            ////    ParametricAttributeGroup pag = new ParametricAttributeGroup(breadcrumbCategories[0].Id, breadcrumbCategories[0].Name);
            ////    pag.ParametricAttributes.Add(new ParametricAttribute(breadcrumbCategories[1].Id, breadcrumbCategories[1].Name));
            ////    plist.Add(pag);
            ////}
        }

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Dimension");
        dt.Columns.Add("DimensionID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Attribute");
        dt.Columns.Add("AttributeID");
        dt.Columns.Add("CheckBox");
        dt.Columns.Add("CheckBoxState");

        DataRow dr;

        List<ParametricAttributeGroup> translatedAttGrp = sri.ParametricDimensions;

        LanguageDataAccess.GetTranslatedAttributes(translatedAttGrp, Language.CurrentLanguageCulture);

        foreach (ParametricAttributeGroup attributeGroup in translatedAttGrp)
        {
            ParametricAttribute attribute = attributeGroup.ParametricAttributes[0];

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Dimension"] = attributeGroup.Name;
            dr["DimensionID"] = attributeGroup.Id;
            dr["Attribute"] = attribute.Value;
            dr["AttributeID"] = attribute.Id;
            dr["CheckBox"] = "false";

            string grpname = attributeGroup.Name;
            // -- get the original name instead of the translated name for comparision --
            if (attributeGroup is LocalizationParametricAttributeGroup)
            {
                grpname = ((LocalizationParametricAttributeGroup)attributeGroup).OriginalName;
            }

            if (grpname == "Manufacturer")
            {
                dr["Dimension"] = Resources.MyMouser.lblManufacturer;
                dr["CheckBoxState"] = "0";
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowPosition);
                rowPosition++;
            }
            else if (grpname == "Product Category")
            {
                // -- don't show product category if this product is under Unclassified --

                isUnclassified = breadcrumbCategories.Any(cat => cat.Name == Resources.MyMouser.lblUnclassified);

                if (!isUnclassified)
                {
                    dr["Dimension"] = attributeGroup.Name;
                    dr["Attribute"] = templateCat.Name;
                    dr["AttributeID"] = templateCat.Id;
                    dr["CheckBoxState"] = "0";
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowPosition);
                    rowPosition++;
                }
            }
            else if (grpname == "Unclassified")
            {
                dr["Dimension"] = Resources.MyMouser.lblUnclassified;
                dr["CheckBoxState"] = "0";
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowPosition);
                rowPosition++;
            }
            else if (grpname == "RoHS - Mouser")
            {
                dr["Dimension"] = Resources.MyMouser.litHeaderRoHS;
                dr["Attribute"] = SearchHelper.CreateRoHSLabel(sri,sri.EnRoHSStatus, isUnclassified,IsMobilePage);
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowPosition);
                rowPosition++;
            }
            else if (grpname == "Standard Pack Qty")
            {
                dr["Dimension"] = Resources.MyMouser.lblfactrPakcQty;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        // -- sort the visiable fields --
        if (customDimSortOrder != null)
        {
            for (int dimSortIndex = 0; dimSortIndex < customDimSortOrder.Count; dimSortIndex++)
            {
                foreach (DataRow oldRow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (customDimSortOrder.AllKeys[dimSortIndex] == oldRow["DimensionID"].ToString())
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Dimension"] = oldRow["Dimension"];
                        dr["DimensionID"] = oldRow["DimensionID"];
                        dr["Attribute"] = oldRow["Attribute"];
                        dr["AttributeID"] = oldRow["AttributeID"];
                        dr["CheckBoxState"] = "0";
                        dt.Rows.Remove(oldRow);
                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowPosition);
                        rowPosition++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //aliases information - shawn weng
        if (sri.Aliases != "")
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Dimension"] = Resources.MyMouser.lblpartaliases;
            dr["DimensionID"] = 0;
            dr["Attribute"] = sri.Aliases;
            dr["AttributeID"] = 0;
            dr["CheckBox"] = "false";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        try
        {
            DataList dl1 = (DataList) this.FindControl("dlspec");
            dl1.DataSource = dt;
            dl1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    protected void dlspec_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            && e.Item.DataItem != null)
        {
            // -- checkbox --
            var ck = e.Item.FindControl("FindSimilarCheckbox") as CheckBox;
            if (ck != null)
            {
                ck.ID = ck.Text;
                ck.Text = "";

                var lbldim = e.Item.FindControl("lblDimension") as Label;
                if (lbldim != null)
                {
                    if (lbldim.Text.Contains(Resources.MyMouser.lblManufacturer) || lbldim.Text.Contains(Resources.MyMouser.lblProductCategory))
                    {
                        ck.Checked = true;
                    }
                    if (lbldim.Text.Contains(Resources.MyMouser.lblfactrPakcQty))
                    {

                        string PackageQtylnk = "<a href=JAVASCRIPT:OpenFactoryQty();>" + Resources.MyMouser.lblfactrPakcQty + "</a>";
                        lbldim.Text = string.Format(PackageQtylnk);
                        lbldim.CssClass = "factorypackage";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the ascx page markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="ProductSpecifications.ascx.cs" Inherits="MouserWeb.Controls.Controls_ProductSpecifications" %>
<asp:DataList ID="dlspec" runat="server" GridLines="Vertical" OnItemDataBound="dlspec_ItemDataBound">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="alt-grey" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="550px">
            <tr>
                <td class="leftcol">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDimension" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Dimension") %>'></asp:Label>:
                </td>
                <td class="ProductDetailData">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Attribute") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="find-similar">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="FindSimilarCheckbox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBox")=="true"? true:false %>'
                        Text='<%# Eval("AttributeID") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("CheckBoxState")=="0"? true:false %>' />
                    <%--<input name='<%# Eval("DimensionID") %>' id='<%# Eval("DimensionID") %>' type="checkbox" checked='<%# Eval("CheckBox")=="true"? true:false %>' />--%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Does anything seem wrong?? Please let me know if i can provide more information(code) about this...Thanks in advance for your valuable help

Comment: Where are you instantiating the datalist?

Comment: do i have to? the code I pasted above is from the code behind file of the user control to which the datalist is registered in. Couldnt I just take the ID of the Datalist as declared in the User control and assign a data source?

Comment: Sorry about that...I meant datatable not datalist.

Comment: yes ... i checked on that ... it is not null..it has rows in it. the problem seems to be in the 'dlspec' the datalist itself..

Comment: i just checked and found out that the 'dlspec' is coming out as null... do i have to initiate it in some manner?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to. If that is where you are getting the exception then I would think that your datatable is null considering that your sample above adds a datarow `if(sri.Aliases != "")`. Edit your question to include some more code.

Comment: @Rich added full code behind...please check and let me know... appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I resolved this... 
So the DisplaySpecification(...) method was being called from the Page_load() of the aspx page to which the user control is registered to.
I moved this call to the Page_PreRender() event of the aspx and it worked fine.
The reason being that the user control actually doesnt get loaded until the aspx page_load() event completes. That is why I had been getting the 'dlspec' as a null.
I appreciate all the help you guys have been...you're awesome.

Thanks Again

Comment: although you won't get any points, you can accept your own answer to give a quick visual cue to others that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Done... Sorry I didn't do it earlier

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is that `dt` is not set.

The next most like cause is that the exception is actually thrown in `dlspec_ItemDataBound`.

This is why it is fairly critical to look at the exception call stack and, if available, include it in your question.

To get a good amount of useful information out of an exception that is caught in your code, you can call it's ToString method. For example, in your catch block:

```
Console.Write(ex.ToString();
```

**Update**

I have an idea about the source of the problem, which is one that we have encountered numerous times (assuming you are using a web application project):

If you move a control from one page/user control to another by just cutting and pasting the markup from the page/user control source **without** switching to design mode after making your changes, visual studio does not always update the references in the designer file.

If you open the designer file for the user control, you can confirm this by searching for dlspec. If it is not in there, this is the source of your problem.

Because we have been hit by this numerous times, whenever we move controls like this, we always switch into design mode, dirty something, then save. And to be safe we usually double-check the designer files to ensure the previous entry was removed and the new entry readded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... firstly the dt is set(i have checked on that)..secondly i havent yet called the databind on the control so it does not go to the ItemDataBound and does not throw the exception there.. my only suspicion is that the "dlspec" is coming out as null?? do i have to do something to instantiate it before trying to populate it?

Comment: added more code to my question...can you see if it makes more sense now...thanks again

Comment: -1: Please either add "throw;" or otherwise show that you don't really intend readers to copy this code as-is. I'll remove downvote then.

Comment: Sorry, was just trying to show debugging code (we have centralized exception handling, so rethrowing is never a concern for us, which is why I forgot to include it). throw has been added.

Comment: @karry: Updated the answer with what I think may be a resolution to your issue.

Comment: I was thinking this too, but got side tracked =\ I agree with @competent_tech what he described in his update has happened to me in the past.

Comment: added the resolution to this as an answer..please take a look ..thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 2):

If your DataList is coming out null, then the problem is a result of the FindControl not finding your datalist control. Here is a good [article](http://odetocode.com/Articles/116.aspx) by Scott Allen on this topic. If the DataTable is null then its getting wiped out somewhere in your code.

Try this to pinpoint the problem:

```
DataTable dt1 = dt; // Set breakpoint here; check dt1 and dl1 to pinpoint prob
DataList dl1 = (DataList) this.FindControl("dlspec");
dl1.DataSource = dt1;
dl1.DataBind();
```

Set your breakpoint where I indicated in the comment and step thru it to see if the datatable is null. Then check and see if the FindControl method returns the control or if it's null.

Comment: -1 for try/catch/throw. If you mean that as a debugging tool, then say so and show where to set the breakpoint. I'll then remove the downvote.

Comment: @John No, I don't mean that as a debugging tool. Thats the user's original code. I am recommending for him to set the datatable to a new datatable and set the breakpoint there so he can determine whether or not the datatable is null and then step thru to see if the control is returned by the find control method. FYI - there is a comment telling him where to set the break point.

Comment: Ouch. He posted so much code that I didn't notice that. Still, two wrongs don't make a right. Please fix your answer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It sounds like you're suggesting that this is an improper use of the try/catch (or at least unecessary). I agree, in fact, if its any consolation, I try to avoid try/catch blocks unless I am going to wrap the exception in something or take some other action as a result of the exception. There is obviously more going on here than a misplaced try/catch block -- I was trying to focus on the problem instead of nit-picking the guys code.

Comment: I have no problem with you not nitpicking the code - just don't repeat the OP's mistakes.